# A recursive function that returns a string and a bool

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a recursive function that determines whether or not a word can be spelled
using only element symbols. It will take two parameters: the word to be spelt and a list of the 118 elements symbols. the function will
return two results: **a Boolean value indicating whether or not a spelling was found,
and the string of symbols used to achieve the spelling (or an empty string if no spelling
exists)**. It should ignore capitalization when searching for a spelling. Display the names of the elements along with the sequences of symbols. For example, one line of my output
will be:

Silver can be spelled as SiLvEr

```
inf = open('elements.txt', 'r')
whole = list(inf)
d_whole = {}

for element in whole:
    element = element.rstrip().split(',')
    d_whole[element[1]] = element[2]

inf.close()
symbols = d_whole.keys()

def isSpelled(word, symbols):
    pass
```

I'm just lost in "the function will return two results: a boolean and a string". I'm wondering how to make a function return both at once.

Comment: you can simply return them as a tuple: `return True, "SiLvEr"`. You can then unpack those values as variable in the caller: `is_spelled, symbols_used = isSpelled(word, symbols)`

Comment: Won't this affect the base cases on next recursions?

Comment: @O'BrienZimeTaga Well, that is basically the entire purpose of doing recursion in the first place...

Comment: This problem sounds like a job for **dynamic programming**.